# Nav bar above video element

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a website with both a navigation bar and a background video on the home page.

```css
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 200);
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999999;
}

div>ul {
  width: 98%;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 240, 240);
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="stages.html">Stages</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="setlists.html">Setlists</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="booking.html">Tickets</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>


<div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="description">Vaporfest presents the first festival dedicated entirely to the 80s and 90s! Vaporfest is the ideal location to go for a nostalgia trip! Relive the best time of your life at Vaporfest!</p>
</div>
```

The code is supposed to display the navigation bar above the video, but instead it shows the video above the navigation bar.

How do I get the navigation bar to appear above the background video?

Comment: I already see a problem with your code. All your html elements need to be _inside_ the ```<body>``` tag. Your ```.description``` rule is also missing a closing ```}```.

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index:-1 to #myVideo` and `z-index:999999 to .nav-bar` will work

```css
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 200);
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999999;
}

div>ul {
  width: 98%;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 240, 240);
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="stages.html">Stages</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="setlists.html">Setlists</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="booking.html">Tickets</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
    <li class="nav-bar"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>


<div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="description">Vaporfest presents the first festival dedicated entirely to the 80s and 90s! Vaporfest is the ideal location to go for a nostalgia trip! Relive the best time of your life at Vaporfest!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and the text appeared above the navigation bar

Comment: which text can you share more details on that?

Comment: the text in the '''p''' element appears above both the video and the nav bar, when the nav bar should be separate from the text. As in, the text should appear below the nav bar.

Comment: This was with the '''z-index''' tags added to the CSS file

Comment: so `z-index to p tag` also

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I am still having the problem I described earlier; The text and the nav bar appear to overlap each other.